# Type error _co.:Registration Page notfound

Tags: angular

> i have a login page and registration page i provide RegisterNow button
>   in my login page beloow login from. I declare RegisterNow() method in
>   my login Component.html when I run my application it work fine when
>   click on login button but my problme is when  I click on my
>   registerNow button it cannot open my  registration page it open my
>   error custom error paage.
>
> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.co.in/
>   was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome
>   will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set
>   with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer
>   tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
>
> Login.component.html

```
<div class="app-body">
  <main class="main d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
          <div class="card-group">
            <div class="card p-4">
              <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                  <h1>Login</h1>
                  <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
                  <small *ngIf='invalidLogin'>{{errorMessage}}</small>
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"  [(ngModel)]="username" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:
                      true}" autocomplete="username" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group mb-4">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:
                      true}"  autocomplete="current-password" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-4" (click)=handleLogin()>Login</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-right">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link px-0">Forgot password?</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none" style="width:44%">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <div>
                  <h2>Sign up</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active mt-3"[routerLink]="['registration']"  (click)="registerNow( (click)="registerNow()">Register Now!</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

> Login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { HardcodeauthService } from '../../service/hardcodeauth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent implements  OnInit{

  username ='nilmani'
  password = 'rock'
  errorMessage='Invalid Credential'
  invalidLogin = false

  constructor( private router : Router,
    private hardcodeauthservice :HardcodeauthService){}

  ngOnInit(){

  }
  registerNow(){
      this.router.navigate(['/registration'])
  }
  handleLogin(){
    // if (this.username==='nilmani' && this.password==='dumy') {
    if (this.hardcodeauthservice.authenticate(this.username,this.password)) {
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard'])
      this.invalidLogin=false
    }else{
      this.invalidLogin=true
    }
    // console.log(this.username)
    // console.log(this.password)
  }


 }
```

> Register.component.html

```
<div class="app-body">
  <main class="main d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
          <div class="card mx-4">
            <div class="card-body p-4">
              <form>
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <p class="text-muted">Create your account</p>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="username" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-4">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                  </div>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat password" autocomplete="new-password" required>
                </div>
                <button type="button"  class="btn  btn-success">Create Account</button>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer p-4">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <button class="btn btn-block btn-facebook" type="button"><span>facebook</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <button class="btn btn-block btn-twitter" type="button"><span>twitter</span></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

> Register.component.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'register.component.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit(){

  }


}
```

> app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// Import Containers
import { DefaultLayoutComponent } from './containers';

import { P404Component } from './views/error/404.component';
import { P500Component } from './views/error/500.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './views/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './views/register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './views/login/login.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: P404Component,
    data: {
      title: 'Page 404'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '500',
    component: P500Component,
    data: {
      title: 'Page 500'
    }
   },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Login Page'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Dashboard Page'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Register Page'
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'base',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/base/base.module').then(m => m.BaseModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'buttons',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/buttons/buttons.module').then(m => m.ButtonsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'charts',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/chartjs/chartjs.module').then(m => m.ChartJSModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'icons',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/icons/icons.module').then(m => m.IconsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'notifications',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/notifications/notifications.module').then(m => m.NotificationsModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'theme',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/theme/theme.module').then(m => m.ThemeModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'widgets',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/widgets/widgets.module').then(m => m.WidgetsModule)
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', component:P404Component}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Show your routes

Comment: this my routes links which i define in my app riuteing

Comment: The `/regitration` route does not exist, it's `/register`

Answer (score 1):

The samesite warning has nothing to do with preventing your routing to work- - Chrome is just spreading the word about this new standard to increase developer adoption.. There might be an actual problem with the routing.

Make sure you have register your path in the app-routing.module.ts.

In your registerNow() function you can call your route this way

```
registerNow(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/registration');
}
```

Else, instead of calling a button click function to execute the route you can execute the route in the button itself.

```
<button [routerLink]="['registration']">home</button >
```

Either of the methods would work fine.

Comment: if i do this way i got jsonp?c=_jp.a4s2rve:1 Uncaught TypeError: _jp.a4s2rve is not a function
    at jsonp?c=_jp.a4s2rve:1  this type of error